# How to make prestashop top-menu vertical on mobile

Tags: css, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How do I make my top-menu vertical and only displaying one item per line when resized to mobile-devices?

Right now it looks like this(Prestashop 1.6 mobile top-menu-fail):

[image]

In advance thanks for the advice!

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo. Nobody can solve your problem by image.

Comment: my store is http://www.coverlovers.dk

Answer (score 1):

You can add `display:block;` to `li`.

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
{
 .sf-menu > li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    border-right: none;
    display: block;
  }
}
```